# Powershell + EWS script to move all text messages to Inbox/SMS subfolder

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I'm hoping someone more experienced than me can post a Powershell script example (using the simplest possible method) that will...

Identify all messages that use **"Text Message" OR "Multimedia Message" forms**... then, move them to the Inbox/SMS subfolder.

Basically, I'm just trying to reproduce what my Outlook 2010 Rule does, except via command line.

If there's a pre-made cmdlet that does this already; with an example of what Im trying to do, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that with something like this

```
    $MailboxName = $args[0]

## Load Managed API dll  
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.1\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"  

## Set Exchange Version  
$ExchangeVersion = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2010_SP2  

## Create Exchange Service Object  
$service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService($ExchangeVersion)  

## Set Credentials to use two options are availible Option1 to use explict credentials or Option 2 use the Default (logged On) credentials  

#Credentials Option 1 using UPN for the windows Account  
$psCred = Get-Credential  
$creds = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($psCred.UserName.ToString(),$psCred.GetNetworkCredential().password.ToString())  
$service.Credentials = $creds      

#Credentials Option 2  
#service.UseDefaultCredentials = $true  

## Choose to ignore any SSL Warning issues caused by Self Signed Certificates  

## Code From http://poshcode.org/624
## Create a compilation environment
$Provider=New-Object Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider
$Compiler=$Provider.CreateCompiler()
$Params=New-Object System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters
$Params.GenerateExecutable=$False
$Params.GenerateInMemory=$True
$Params.IncludeDebugInformation=$False
$Params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.DLL") | Out-Null

$TASource=@'
  namespace Local.ToolkitExtensions.Net.CertificatePolicy{
    public class TrustAll : System.Net.ICertificatePolicy {
      public TrustAll() { 
      }
      public bool CheckValidationResult(System.Net.ServicePoint sp,
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate cert, 
        System.Net.WebRequest req, int problem) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
'@ 
$TAResults=$Provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource($Params,$TASource)
$TAAssembly=$TAResults.CompiledAssembly

## We now create an instance of the TrustAll and attach it to the ServicePointManager
$TrustAll=$TAAssembly.CreateInstance("Local.ToolkitExtensions.Net.CertificatePolicy.TrustAll")
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy=$TrustAll

## end code from http://poshcode.org/624

## Set the URL of the CAS (Client Access Server) to use two options are availbe to use Autodiscover to find the CAS URL or Hardcode the CAS to use  

#CAS URL Option 1 Autodiscover  
$service.AutodiscoverUrl($MailboxName,{$true})  
"Using CAS Server : " + $Service.url   

#CAS URL Option 2 Hardcoded  

#$uri=[system.URI] "https://casservername/ews/exchange.asmx"  
#$service.Url = $uri    

## Optional section for Exchange Impersonation  

#$service.ImpersonatedUserId = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ImpersonatedUserId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConnectingIdType]::SmtpAddress, $MailboxName) 
function FolderIdFromPath{
    param (
            $FolderPath = "$( throw 'Folder Path is a mandatory Parameter' )"
          )
    process{
        ## Find and Bind to Folder based on Path  
        #Define the path to search should be seperated with \  
        #Bind to the MSGFolder Root  
        $folderid = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::MsgFolderRoot,$MailboxName)   
        $tfTargetFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$folderid)  
        #Split the Search path into an array  
        $fldArray = $FolderPath.Split("\") 
         #Loop through the Split Array and do a Search for each level of folder 
        for ($lint = 1; $lint -lt $fldArray.Length; $lint++) { 
            #Perform search based on the displayname of each folder level 
            $fvFolderView = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderView(1) 
            $SfSearchFilter = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderSchema]::DisplayName,$fldArray[$lint]) 
            $findFolderResults = $service.FindFolders($tfTargetFolder.Id,$SfSearchFilter,$fvFolderView) 
            if ($findFolderResults.TotalCount -gt 0){ 
                foreach($folder in $findFolderResults.Folders){ 
                    $tfTargetFolder = $folder                
                } 
            } 
            else{ 
                "Error Folder Not Found"  
                $tfTargetFolder = $null  
                break  
            }     
        }  
        if($tfTargetFolder -ne $null){
            return $tfTargetFolder.Id.UniqueId.ToString()
        }
    }
}


$TextMessageClass = "IPM.Note.Mobile.SMS"
$MMSMessageClass =  "IPM.Note.Mobile.MMS"

$sfItemSearchFilter1 = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::ItemClass,$TextMessageClass) 
$sfItemSearchFilter2 = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::ItemClass,$MMSMessageClass)  

#SearchFilter collection Or
$sfCollection = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+SearchFilterCollection([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.LogicalOperator]::Or);
$sfCollection.Add($sfItemSearchFilter1)
$sfCollection.Add($sfItemSearchFilter2)

# Bind to the Inbox Folder
$folderid= new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox,$MailboxName)   
$Inbox = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$folderid)

# Get Folder to Move Item to

$fldId = FolderIdFromPath -FolderPath "\Inbox\SMS"
$SubFolderId =  new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId($fldId)
$SubFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$SubFolderId)
$Itemids = @()
if($SubFolder -ne $null){
    #Define ItemView to retrive just 1000 Items    
    $ivItemView =  New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(1000)    
    $fiItems = $null    
    do{    
        $fiItems = $service.FindItems($Inbox.Id,$sfCollection,$ivItemView)    
        #[Void]$service.LoadPropertiesForItems($fiItems,$psPropset)  
        foreach($Item in $fiItems.Items){           
            Write-Host ("Moving " + $Item.Subject)
            $Itemids += $Item
        }    
        $ivItemView.Offset += $fiItems.Items.Count    
    }while($fiItems.MoreAvailable -eq $true) 
    #Total Items Processed Varible
    $nmbProcessed = 0
    if($Itemids.Count -gt 0){
        write-host ("Move " + $Itemids.Count + " Items")
        #Create Collection for Move Batch
        $type = ("System.Collections.Generic.List"+'`'+"1") -as "Type"
        $type = $type.MakeGenericType("Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemId" -as "Type")
        $BatchItemids = [Activator]::CreateInstance($type)
        #Varible to Track BatchSize
        $batchSize = 0
        foreach($iiID in $Itemids){
            $nmbProcessed++
            $BatchItemids.Add($iiID.Id)
            if($iiID.Size -ne $null){
                $batchSize += $iiID.Size
            }
            #if BatchCount greator then 50 or larger the 10 MB Move Batch
            if($BatchItemids.Count -eq 50 -bor $batchSize -gt (10*1MB)){
                $Result = $null
                $Result = $service.MoveItems($BatchItemids,$SubFolder.Id)
                [INT]$collectionCount = 0
                [INT]$Rcount = 0  
                [INT]$Errcount = 0
                if($Result -ne $null){
                    foreach ($res in $Result){ 
                        if ($res.Result -eq [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResult]::Success){  
                            $Rcount++  
                        } 
                        else{
                            $Errcount++
                        }
                        $collectionCount++
                    }  
                }
                else{
                    Write-Host -foregroundcolor red ("Move Result Null Exception")
                }
                Write-host ($Rcount.ToString() + " Items Moved Successfully " + "Total Processed " + $nmbProcessed + " Total Folder Items " + $Itemids.Count) 
                if($Errcount -gt 0){
                    Write-Host -foregroundcolor red ($Errcount.ToString() + " Error failed Moved")
                }
                $BatchItemids.Clear()
                $batchSize = 0
            }
        }
        if($BatchItemids.Count -gt 0){
            $Result = $service.MoveItems($BatchItemids,$SubFolder.Id) 
            [INT]$Rcount = 0  
            [INT]$Errcount = 0 
            foreach ($res in $Result){  
                if ($res.Result -eq [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResult]::Success){  
                    $Rcount++  
                }  
                else{
                    $Errcount++
                }
            }  
            Write-host ($Rcount.ToString() + " Items Moved Successfully")
            if($Errcount -gt 0){
                Write-Host -foregroundcolor red ($Errcount.ToString() + " Error failed Moved")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers
Glen